# Why are there critical points at these points?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I'm not understanding how my book found critical points at (0,2) and (0,-2). I found that

```
fx = 2x - 2 = 0 -> x = 1,

and fy = 2y = 0 -> y = 0,
```

so I thought the only critical point would be (1,0). but the book says critical points at (0,2) and (0,-2). Why at these points? I thought you were only supposed to solve for points in the gradient  = 0.

Comment: Looks like there's a mistake in the book.

Comment: it says  theres a maximum at f(0,+/- 2) = 4, and minimum at f(1,0) as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1,0) is indeed the only critical point, but it's not enough to check just critical points to determine the absolute maximum and minimum. Just as for one-variable functions, you must also check all the points on the boundary of the region.

Comment: But isn't there infinitely many points to check? How do I do that mathematically so I'm not plugging in a bunch of random numbers? And what do I even plug them into or how do I check them?

Comment: The boundaries of the triangle are line segments. Find the equations of those 3 lines. By substituting each of those equations into f(x,y), you'll get a one-variable formula for f(x,y) along each of the 3 sides. We're looking for the max and min along the boundary, so solve the corresponding one-variable max-min problem along each of the 3 sides. Once you've found the max and min along the boundary, you can compare them with the value of f at the critical point (1,0). It's the same process as you did for one-variable functions. You may want to go back and review that.

Comment: Recall that in one variable calculus there are also infinitely many points to consider in every max/min problem. We found a way to handle that there.

Comment: How do you find the equations of those three lines? I want to say it has to do with parameterization, but not sure how to apply it in this case...

Comment: i know I can use slope intercept form but is there an easier way using parameterization?

Comment: ok, once i get a bunch of one variable formulas in terms of x, how do I get y for each of those x values?

Comment: alright I see how I got absolute max at (0,+-2) now by finding an equation of all three lines, plugging them into f(x), and then plugging in the smallest value of x and largest value of x in each, then figuring out which point had the largest and smallest value. the largest value is 4 at both those points and smallest is at a local minimum given earlier. but I think I need to know how to do this type of problem by using parametric equations. Can anyone show me the process that way?

Comment: Finding the equation of the lines *is* using a parametric form, where the parameter is called x instead of t.  If you want it to look more like the "usual" parametric form with a parameter called t, you could write a line like y=2x+3 in the form x=t, y=2t+3. But that's just an unnecessary complication.